# PhantomJS Height Not Changing

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, pdfkit

I'm using PhantomJS in conjunction with Python's PDFKit to generate PDFs. I have the following Node script my Python script is calling to get the size of every page's body:

```
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.viewportSize = {width: 20, height: 1200};

        page.open(args[0]).then(function(status) {
            page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js').then(function(err) {
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    return $('body').height();
                }).then(function(height) {
                    console.log(height);
                    ph.exit();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I'm having trouble with Phantom calculating the height appropriately with jQuery. As you can see, I've purposefully put the width as "20" just to illustrate that Phantom's window size doesn't seem to properly be setting. Whether it's 20, 200, 2000, I get the same height from jQuery's height() method per page (different per page, but always the same on a given specific page regardless of the width setting), which leads me to believe the height must be staying static regardless of the viewportSize being set manually. Guidance as to why this may be happening is much appreciated!

Comment: You would need to use `page.set('viewportSize', ...)` and consume the returned promise

Comment: Like this? I'm fairly new to using Promises...

page.set('viewportSize', {width: 20, height: 1200}).then(function(err) {
    page.open(args[0]).then(function(status) {
        ...
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

*$('body').height()* means getting the height of document.body, which would be a regular number decided by the height of HTML.
You could get the right value through *window.screen.height*